# Vector of vectors transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Lets say I have a vector $v\in A^n$ where $A = \{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Let $v^i_j$ be the ith component of the jth component of $v$

I then define a transformation (for example) $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow A^2$ where $T:(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto ((a_1,a_2),(a_3,a_4))^T$ ?

Edit: How can I define a function $F$ such that if I wanted to get the 3rd component of the vector in the domain of T, it would return $v_2^1$

Something like:

$$F(k) = (i,j)$$ where k is the kth component of the domain vector and i is the ith component of the jth component of the target vector

Edit 2:

Even better, I was able to configure a matrix of vectors to map the vector of vectors to a vector of scalars. Here is an example:

Take

$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
(1,0) & (0,0)\\
(0,1) & (0,0)\\
(0,0) & (1,0)\\
(0,0) & (0,1)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
v = ((a_1,a_2)^T,(a_3,a_4)^T)^T
$$

Then
$$Qv = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)^T$$

I'm not sure if this is valid, but would appreciate any feedback here

Comment: Seems like you already defined it. So what's your question?

Comment: How can I create a formula for the indices so if I wanted, for example, to pull the 3rd component in the domain vector, i'd get $v_2^1$

Comment: You mean how to notate the $k$th component of $v\in A^n$, interpreting $v$ as having $2n$ components? The $k$th component would be $v^{(k\bmod 2)+1}_{\lfloor (k+1)/2\rfloor}$ if you *really* wanted a "formula" for it.

Comment: If you want a function which takes a value in one of the components as an argument and the index of that component as the output, that would be ill-defined if the vector had any repeated values in its components, but otherwise this description would count as a definition in and of itself.

Comment: How would multiplying a "vector of vectors" by a matrix of scalars return anything whose entries weren't still vectors, since the matrix multiplication process involves multiplying the vectors by scalars and then adding them up (if I'm interpreting you correctly)? Is there some context that explains why you're asking these sorts of things?

Comment: I didn't mean a matrix of scalars, I meant a matrix of vectors. If this is not matrix multiplication, what area of mathematics is this from?

Comment: Wouldn't multiplying a "matrix of vectors" by a "vector of vectors" require one to multiply vectors by the vectors? What do you think that means? I don't really know what "this" is in your sentence. You've given no context for the strange, random questions.

Comment: this = multiplying a matrix of vectors by a vector of vectors - see edit for details